# How to intercept a static property in java class using AspectJ?

Tags: java, static, aop, aspectj

In the following code snippet I need to execute some logic whenever the property `myList` is accessed. Is it possible?

```
public class Test {
    public static List<String> myList = new ArrayList();

    public static void addData(){
        myList.add("foo");
        myList.add("bar");
    }
    public static void removeData(){
        if(myList.size() > 0){
            myList.remove(0);
        }
    }
    public static void displayData(){
        for (String data : myList) {
            System.out.println("data : "+data);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addData();
        displayData();
        removeData();
        displayData();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is if you make myList private and all of the accessors are within your class.  Otherwise you have to find the memory addresses of myList at runtime and set hardware breakpoints, like a debugger does.

Comment: Lets say it is a private property and all the accessors are in the same class, then could you please help me with the code sample for the interception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can weave code `Before`/`After`/`Around` any access to your field using the following pointcuts :

```
@Aspect
public class TestAccessorsAspect {
    @Pointcut("get(java.util.List com.sample.Test.myList)")
    public void readMyList(){}

    @Pointcut("set(java.util.List com.sample.Test.myList)")
    public void writeMyList(){}
}
```

in .aj syntax, this might look like this :

```
public aspect TestAccessorsAspect {

    pointcut readMyList() : get(java.util.List com.sample.Test.myList);   

    pointcut writeMyList() : set(java.util.List com.sample.Test.myList);   
}
```

Whenever those field are accessed for reading (resp. writing), those pointcuts are going to be triggered.

Comment: You don't need to add the complexity of Aspect Oriented Programming to solve this problem.  Aspects are really meant to cut across multiple classes.  The OP has one class.

Comment: Well as the question was tagged both with `aop` and `aspectj` I assumed the author wanted an answer using aspects.

Comment: Yes I need to use AOP concept, it is the requirement. I just gave a sample code something similar to the actual code. By the way thank you guys for you response.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is simple enough that I do not know if I understand it.  From what you have said a very small adjustment answers it.

```
public class Test {
    private static List<String> myList = new ArrayList();

    public static void addData() {
        myListAccessLogic();
        myList.add("foo");

        myListAccessLogic();
        myList.add("bar");
    }
    public static void removeData() {
        myListAccessLogic();
        if(myList.size() > 0) {

            myListAccessLogic();
            myList.remove(0);
        }
    }
    public static void displayData() {
        myListAccessLogic();
        for (String data : myList) {

            myListAccessLogic();
            System.out.println("data : "+data);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        addData();
        displayData();
        removeData();
        displayData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, let me explain you the exact scenario.  I have a situation where a JAR is already available which contains a class(SessionManager) having a static property(an ArrayList of 'User class') to hold the logged-in user data, now when a new User is added to the List, I have to intercept and add some extra info in that object before adding it to the list. Similarly, while accessing that object I will retrieve the already stored (extra)info and perform specific operations.

PS: The JAR doesn't contain source(.java files) but the .class files and I am not allowed to modify anything in that JAR.

Comment: OK, well that makes a big difference because the ArrayList is publicly available and there is code inside of the JAR that may access the ArrayList through paths you don't know about yet.  The first thing to notice is that unless they encrypted their source, you can use one of the JAR->java decompilers, which will mostly allow you to make sense of what they did and will show you where ArrayList is being accessed.  I use jd-gui on Mac: http://jd.benow.ca but since it is Java you can run it most anywhere.  Do that and let us know how the ArrayList is being accessed that you do not control.

Comment: Yes @Daniel, I did the same and got to know about SessionManager class and User class. And here is the usage of that list - once a user is successfully logged-in into the application they are storing the user details like userId, userName, sessionId, etc in that list and if the same user tries to log-in from some other browser/ system while keeping the previous session on, they are blocking it giving a message.

Comment: OK, so can you wrap all of the functions that touch the ArrayList you are interested in?  So when a user comes in from a browser, does the browser call the JAR directly, or can you intercede with your code?  Because if people can access the ArrayList in the JAR that you cannot modify, without an interposing JAR that you write, then you are stuck.  You have to poll the ArrayList in the JAR regularly to know when it has been modified.  But if a browser could instead connect to your JAR, then you can insert your monitoring code while keeping the full functionality of the JAR you want to monitor.